# Cannot create new page layouts for account in Professional Edition

Tags: page-layout, professional-edition

I am unable to create new page layouts for professional edition. Is there a work around to make that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the Salesforce documentation :

> Enterprise, Unlimited, Performance, and Developer Edition
>   organizations can
>        create different page layouts for use by different profiles and record types
>        and set field-level security settings to further restrict users’ access to specific fields.

Professional Edition seems to not allow you to create layout.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutoverview.htm&language=en